# Execute a function in background when clicking a button with no output being changed (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I want to be able to click a button within my Shiny App. So far so easy.
But when doing so, a function that loads, writes and then saves an excel sheet should be executed "behind the scenes" with no output changed in the App itself.
How can I do this?

Kind regards,

Martin

Comment: Use an `actionButton`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Try to use an **Observer**.

#### in server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    # other code ...
    observe({
        # do_something_button is your actionButton id.
        if (input$do_something_button > 0) {
            # perform behind the scenes analysis here.

            # if you want to send a message to the client side, you can try 
            # something like: 
            message <- list(type="completed", excel_file=saved_file)
            session$sendCustomMesage("background_task", message)
        }

    })
    # other code ...
})
```

#### then write some custom javascript snippet and load it via ui.R:

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("background_task", function(message) {
    console.log("Finished processing: " + message.excel_file);
});
```

In this way when the server completes the background processing, or should an error occur, you can get some feedback on the client side. Maybe you want to notify the user about an error or something.

The reference for using `observe` is [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observe.html)

Comment: Another question: I now have a actionButton that only appears if another action did take place before. So if I take an observer to observe this "dependent" action Button I will always get an error like "argument is of length 0" when I check if(input$depactionButton>0). How can I prevend this? Hope this is understandable. Didnt want to open a whole new question ;)

Comment: Ok the solution is to use first if(!is.null(input$dependenbutton)) and inside then if(input$dependentbutton>0)!

Comment: Hi @MartinDabbelJuSmelter. Glad that you figured out it yourself. Sorry I was busy this morning and didn't notice your comment. I guess in your question, by saying a button will "appear", you meant that you created that button using `updateUI` in `server.R`? If you want to avoid the extra `if` condition, you can use a `conditionalPanel` to wrap around the dependent button and only make it visible after the actionButton is clicked. [The document for conditionalPanel is here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html).

Comment: Let me add a bit explanation. You create *both* buttons in your `ui.R`, but the `dependentButton` is wrapped by a `conditonalPanel` whose `condition` parameter is set as `condition="input.actionButton > 0"`. In this way, when you click the `actionButton`, it increases the counter `input$actionButton`, satisfying the condition specified and hence the dependent button will appear. Note that you use `input.actionButton` in the condition because this condition is evaluated in Javascript, not R. Hence you use "dot", not "dollar sign".

Comment: @XinYin I posted a question on the Google Shiny Users' group, but I wondered if you might have a suggestion. Why does my function fullTimeInfo() execute twice when I push my button once with this code? 
      observe({
        if(input$samp > 0) {
          fullTimeInfo(input$term1, input$term2)
          output$compare <- renderPlot({
            fullTimeInfo()
          }) 
        }
      })